# In c accessing first element of the struct using address of the struct and pointers

Tags: c, linux

I noticed that the `struct` address and the first element address look to be same.
So I tried to access the first element of `struct` using address of the main `struct`.
But I am getting an error.

In compatible type of argument 1 of the display.

What mistake I am making here?

***Code***

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define BASE(class) *(&class)

struct animal {
    int walk;
    int hear;
};

struct bird {
    struct animal *base;
    int fly;
};

void display(struct animal *common) {
    printf("All animal details hear=%d  walk=%d ", common->hear, common->walk);
}

int main() {
    struct bird peacockptr;
    struct animal base;
    base.hear = 1;
    base.walk = 1;
    peacockptr.base = &base;

    struct bird *pecock = &peacockptr;
    pecock->fly = 1;

    printf("base address using peacock struct %d\n",
       BASE(peacockptr));  // both are printing same address
    printf("base address animal %d\n",
       &base);  // both are printing same address

    display(&base);     // here it work
    display(BASE(peacockptr));  // getting error
}
```

Comment: Pointers have not only values but types as well. Even if numerical value of two pointers is the same, it doesn't mean they are interchangeable or compatible. You need to use proper types.

Comment: FYI most c++ compilers make base a value field instead of a pointer field. that way sizeof(derived) = sizeof(base) + sizeof(derived fields). In case you are trying to mimic that behavior.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Can i make it work. What cast i need to in display(BASE(peacockptr)); to make it work. I tried even like this display((struct animal *)BASE(peacockptr)); But did not work

Comment: You can also use `void` pointers: https://wandbox.org/permlink/SCugBZgzP5vrS8ad

Comment: @bob thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned you can drop your `BASE` macro as the operators cancel out on pointers.

I cleared up and corrected your code a bit and explained where you where going wrong:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct animal
{
    int walk;
    int hear;
};

struct bird
{
    struct animal *base;
    int fly;
};

void display(struct animal *common)
{
    printf("All animal details hear=%d  walk=%d\n",common->hear, common->walk);
}

int main()
{
    struct bird peacock; // removed ptr suffix, since it is not a pointer
    struct animal base ;

    base.hear=1;
    base.walk=1;

    peacock.base= &base;

    struct bird *peacockptr = &peacock;
    peacockptr->fly=1;

    printf("base address using peacock struct %p\n",  (void *)*(struct animal **)peacockptr); //This is the address of base using peackockptr
    printf("base address animal %p\n", (void *)&base); //This is the address of base

    display(&base);
    display(*(struct animal **)peacockptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Note that the adress of `peackock` equals the address of the first element of the struct which is a `struct animal *`. So you have to cast `peacockptr` to `struct animal **` (because it is pointing to the first element which is of type `struct animal *`) and then dereference it to get the address of `base`.

Comment: I got now my mistake @Osiris. Thank you so much all.

Comment: I think its better to add `(void *)` for casting %p argument in both of `printf()`  to resolve this warning: `warning: format ‘%p’ expects argument of type ‘void *’, but argument 2 has type ‘struct animal *’ [-Wformat=]`

Comment: `(void*)*(struct animal **)peacockptr` and `(void*) &base`

Comment: @EsmaeelE Not only better, it would be undefined behavior otherwise. Thank you, good catch.

Answer (score 3):

It's true that the address of a struct is the same as the address of its first member.  However, they have different **types**.  One has type `struct animal *` and the other has type `struct base *`.

You are allowed to convert between the two in this case, however you need an explicit cast to do so.

```
display((struct animal *)BASE(peacockptr));
```

Also, regarding the way you have your `BASE` macro defined:

```
#define BASE(class) *(&class)
```

The `*` and `&` operators cancel each other out, so this is effectively a no-op.  `BASE(peacockptr)` is equivalent to `peacockptr`.

The reason it fails for you now with the cast, is because you have `peacockptr` defined as an *instance* and `pecock` as a *pointer*, i.e. you confused yourself with the naming.  Switch the names to reflect the usage:

```
struct bird peacock;
struct animal base;
base.hear=1;
base.walk=1;
peacock.base= &base;

struct bird *peacockptr =&peacock;
peacockptr->fly=1;
```

Comment: `peacockptr` is still not pointing to a `struct animal`, because `base` is a pointer. Shouldn't it be `peacockptr.base`? So if OP wants to mimic classes he should make base a value field. then the cast would be valid.

Comment: @dbush I tried this display((struct animal *)BASE(peacockptr));    But i get error can't convert to pointer type error

Comment: @Vipin  That's because `peacockptr` is not a pointer to `struct bird`.  It's an *instance* of `struct bird` and `peacock` is a pointer.  You confused yourself by using names that didn't reflect what they were.  Switch the names.

Comment: @Vipin either change `peacockptr` to be a pointer or pass it this way `display((struct animal *) &peacockptr)`

Comment: @gmoshkin sorry i did not understand. Can you please update the example in answer part.

Comment: `display((struct animal *)BASE(peacockptr));`. `peacockptr` is of type `struct bird`. Aren't you casting a `struct bird` to `struct animal *` here?

Comment: @Vipin I added an update to show where the confusion is.

Comment: @osiris Yes. i am trying to cast the address of first member using address of the struct. Because both the address are same.

Comment: @dbush thanks for finding it. But i tried  display((struct animal *) &peacockptr) this suggestion. It was giving some different value. Is it like it is not possible in c.

Comment: @Vipin It's not working because the first member of `struct bird` is a pointer to `struct animal`, not an instance of `struct animal`.  You need to either dereference the casted pointer or change `struct bird` to contain an instance of `struct animal` instead of a pointer.